# Major troubles with publishing c# windows forms app

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, manifest, publish

I've got this app I've made with one external .dll and one resource (icon image). The .dlland icon are correctly added as resources and the icon is set to be embedded on compilation. I've made sure to specify under PROJECTNAME > Properties > Publish > Prerequisites to include the .net version I'm using as well as windows installer 4.5. After using the publish wizard ("From a CD-ROM or DCD-ROM" was selected, "application won't check for updates" was selected). I feel like I'm doing everything right but after launching the installer on a separate machine and completing a successful installation of the prerequisites AND my program, I get this error when I try to open the .exe... 
https://i.gyazo.com/23b9c42f57694379c93f42a3024645e6.png

** note that the red is just covering the programs name

This has been driving me crazy, I can't get this to open on any other machine.

Extra info can be provided upon request if I miss anything:

- Developed the program on a win7 machine, tried testing on a win7, win8, and win10 machine but non of them worked, all providing the same error message in the link provided
- The installer created from ClickOnce (I think that's what I'm using?) works fine and seems to be installing properly, no errors provided

Comment: The link doesn't connect...

Comment: Can you verify by visual inspection that both the .exe and .dll are present in the target machine?  What happens if you manually copy the app's .exe and the external .dll?  Are you starting the app using a shortcut or by directly double clicking on the .exe?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway yes both are present. The .dll is in the application folder within the publish folder. And I'm directly clicking the .exe